# qml - "toast" like fading message box

Tags: qt, qml, toast, qtquickcontrols2

Is there already something like the android "toast" fading message popup for qml? I surely can create something by myself but I would assume/hope that there already is something like that delivered with Qt / QtQuickControls2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [ToolTip](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-tooltip.html). It is styled like a "toast" when using the Material style.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 360
    height: 520
    visible: true

    Button {
        text: "Button"
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        ToolTip.text: "ToolTip"
        ToolTip.visible: pressed
        ToolTip.timeout: 3000
        ToolTip.delay: 500
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I assume I have to make it fade out and put it to the top of my window by myself though, am I right?

Comment: ToolTip has appropriate enter and exit transitions defined in the Material style. You need to define when to make the tooltip visible, though. There are plenty of examples in the docs.

Comment: I have added an example snippet and a screenshot. I hope this helps.